# How to split a defined string from another string and get the first item after split

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have this string `D:\ASN\Documents\ENU\LO\ANL\File\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf` and I want to exclude this string `D:\ASN\Documents\ENU\LO` from the above string and then get the first string(in this case `ANL`)after the split.

I tried something like this:

```
string fullpath = "D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO\\ANL\\File\\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf"
string[] sep = new string[]{"D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO"};
string [] result = fullpath.split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  foreach (string s in result)
            {
                Console.Write(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(@"\") + 1));
            }
```

But this is giving me `ANL\File\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf"`. Instead I need only `ANL`. How can this be achieved? Is there any other way to get this instead of this way.

TIA

Comment: I wouldn't do that - I would look at the `System.IO.Path` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = fullpath.Replace(samplePath, "").Split('\\')[1];
```

You can replace the first part (samplePath) with nothing, removing it (or you could use Substring to get the second part of the fullPath, counting the characters of samplePath), and then Split the result on '\', getting the second occurrence, which is the result you expect.

Here's a working version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k4tfGP

Comment: `.Split('\')` is throwing an error. So I used `.Split('\\')` and then the output is null. Did i miss anything here?

Comment: Yes, you should split by '\\' (or if you want to split by string you could use .Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.None) ), and then take the second occurrence (with your string, the first one is empty).

Comment: Thanks for the working model. Its working now. Previously we added [0] and thats why it is showing null. But [1] did make the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do a split on the second string when it sees the \?

```
String sampleString = "ANL\File\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf"";
String[] stringArray = sampleString.split("\");
String wantedString = stringArray[0];
```

Comment: Can do that. but I want to if there is any other way to get the same. Because I am using many splits for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what `split()` is intended for. `split()` is generally used to divide your string into multiple sections based on a separator. In your case, you might have wanted to use it to separate the sub-folders by splitting on '\'.

But you want something else -- to remove a section of text. If you know that the text will always be at the start, try this:

```
string result = fullpath.Substring("D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO".Length);
```

This will return the original string, minus the first X characters, where X is exactly the length of the string you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the info on split. But when I did the way you suggested it is giving me `\ANL\LO\File\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf`. But how can I get the `ANL` from this?

Comment: On the result, you can now use split(), with '\\' as the separator, then take the first element of the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string fullpath =
            "D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO\\ANL\\File\\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf";
        string[] sep = new string[] {"D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO"};
        string[] result = fullpath.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string s in result)
        {
            Console.Write(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(@"\") + 1, s.IndexOf(@"\", 2) - 1));
        }
```

String.IndexOf will get you the index of the first, but has overloads giving a starting point. So In this example, I have given the starting point as "2" as your path contains "\\" always.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Its working :) . But I was looking for an easier way to solve this instead of doing this process.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string basepath = "D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO\\";
        string fullpath = "D:\\ASN\\Documents\\ENU\\LO\\ANL\\File\\05003ede-59bf-45c6-bb57-a6111e9f18e0\\linux-cheat-sheet.pdf";

        fullpath = fullpath.Replace(basepath, "");
        string returnValue = fullpath.Remove(fullpath.IndexOf("\\"), fullpath.Length-fullpath.IndexOf("\\"));
```

Worked here...